# inode - move a file which is already opened

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

On linux, on a ext4 partition there is a movie, if I open the movie & watch it, then I move or rename the movie.

After the previous cache use up, it need to read more cache from original file, then it still could do that.

**The question is:**

How file system & inode achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) on a file within the same file system just changes the name that points to the inode.  You can even use `rename()` to move that name into another directory - as long as it's in the same file system:

> The *rename()* function shall change the name of a file. The old
>   argument points to the pathname of the file to be renamed. The new
>   argument points to the new pathname of the file. ...

Note that the POSIX specification for `rename()` is a lot more specific than the C Standard `rename()` specification:

> **7.21.4.2 The `rename` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The rename function causes the file whose name is the string pointed
>   to by `old` to be henceforth known by the name given by the string
>   pointed to by `new` . The file named `old` is no longer accessible by
>   that name.  If a file named by the string pointed to by `new` exists
>   prior to the call to the `rename` function, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The
>   `rename`
>   function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails,
>   269)
>   in
>   which case if the file existed previously it is still known by its original name.

(That's the entire C Standard specification for `rename()`.  Read the [POSIX link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) for a lot more information.)

So how can you rename a file while your watching it in an application?  The underlying inode that your movie-watching process's open file descriptor uses to access the file that you just `rename()`'d doesn't change.

That's the same reason why you can [`unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html) (delete) a file while it's in use - all you're doing is removing the entry that *points to* the inode - one of the *links* to the inode.  The space used by the file isn't freed until the *last* link to the inode is removed - and an open file descriptor counts as a link.  That's also why the function that deletes the directory entry for a file is called `unlink()` - that's all it does.  And yes, a file (inode) can have more than one link pointing to it.

Comment: So, fd refer to inode, before read, it first read inode to get path info, then read, so that even the path changed, it will get the new path before read, is that correct?